# Burger menu not centred properly

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

I created a burger menu in pure CSS, but the problem is that for some reason it's centred by its left side, not middle. I don't really understand why.

Markup:

```
<section id="header">
    <a href="#menu" class="box-shadow-menu" id="navTrigger">
        <div class="navicon">
        </div>
    </a>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #4dc1df;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}

.navicon {
    position: fixed;
    height: 45px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -17.5px;
}

.box-shadow-menu {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
}

.box-shadow-menu:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 4px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 0 white, 0 20px 0 0 white;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jLhnr12p/1/.

Any help to centre this properly would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
.navicon {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}
```

You can't center like this, you can do it by setting left property to 50% and setting negative margin-left (half of the navicon which is 17.5px);

```
.navicon {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -17.5px; // or transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: That was actually something I tried while trying to fix this, but I've updated my code. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: If the `.navicon` will have different sizes, or OP plans to change it often, then a transform might be a better option than a negative margin `transform: translateX(-50%);` with vendor prefixes.

Comment: With your updated code you can use `margin-left: -17.5px` and `left: 50%` for `.box-shadow-menu:before` or you can use `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` like @shirfy suggested.

Comment: I see. I realised that where the a href was originally only hyperlinked one of the three lines, so I restructured the HTML, but not it's not centering properly again.

Comment: I would be careful when using translate, because the click hit box will not be where the visual representation of the hamburger is...

Comment: @Mario Parra it is not working because you used styles for navicon now, and your navicon now is nothing, use these styles on .box-shadow-menu:before. You can even delete this div with class navicon.

Comment: @sniels http://jsfiddle.net/d7b06s4j/ I don't see that what you are saying.

Comment: Hmm, this is an issue I've personally encountered in the past with transform and links. Maybe it was in combination with transition and transform. Or maybe it has been fixed in the browser's. Disregard my warning.